# Get TinyXML to parse just one node

Tags: xml, tinyxml

I am trying to figure out how to give TinyXML a buffer or file which contains more than one XML node, and have it parse only one of them at a time. It appears that TiXmlDocument::Parse() has some functionality for this, since it returns back a char const* pointer, and the pointer returned seems to be past the text.

The reason I want to do this is that I may have truncated or malformed input, and I want to parse as much as I can. For instance:

```
<outer>
    <inner a="b">value</inner>
</outer>
<outer>
    <inner c="d">again</inner>
</outer>
<outer
```

Answer (score 0):

The Parse() method is virtual, you can Parse() any TinyXML Node. In your example:

TiXmlElement ele;
ele.Parse( p, 0 /* the parsing data can be null */, TIXML_ENCODING_UTF8 );

Will read in one element.